# Multiple foreach for different variables? Values duplicating in database

Tags: php, foreach

I was testing a `textarea` box and its corresponding `foreach` code.  Worked successfully.  Basically the code took each value inside of the textarea box and inserted each value into individual rows into the database.

But I want to duplicate this since I have multiple textarea boxes.

Can anyone validate the following code?

```
$text = trim($_POST['BachelorsDegrees']);
$textAr = explode("\n", $text);
$textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim'); // remove any extra \r characters left behind
$textCert = trim($_POST['Certifications']);
$textArCert = explode("\n", $textCert);
$textArCert = array_filter($textArCert, 'trim'); // remove any extra \r characters left behind
$textDip = trim($_POST['Diplomas']);
$textArDip = explode("\n", $textDip);
$textArDip = array_filter($textArDip, 'trim'); // remove any extra \r characters left behind
$textAD = trim($_POST['AssociateDegrees']);
$textArAD = explode("\n", $textAD);
$textArAD = array_filter($textArAD, 'trim'); // remove any extra \r characters left behind
$textMD = trim($_POST['MastersDegrees']);
$textArMD = explode("\n", $textMD);
$textArMD = array_filter($textArMD, 'trim'); // remove any extra \r characters left behind
$textDD = trim($_POST['DoctorateDegrees']);
$textArDD = explode("\n", $textDD);
$textArDD = array_filter($textArDD, 'trim'); // remove any extra \r characters left behind
$textSD = trim($_POST['SpecialDegreePrograms']);
$textArSD = explode("\n", $textSD);
$textArSD = array_filter($textArSD, 'trim'); // remove any extra \r characters left behind


foreach ($textAr as $BachelorsDegrees)
{
    foreach ($textArCert as $Certifications)
    {
    foreach ($textArDip as $Diplomas)
    {
    foreach ($textArAD as $AssociateDegrees)
    {
    foreach ($textArMD as $MastersDegrees)
    {
    foreach ($textArDD as $DoctorateDegrees)
    {
    foreach ($textArSD as $SpecialDegreePrograms)
    {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO College_Courses (Name, BachelorsDegrees, Certifications,Diplomas,AssociateDegrees,MastersDegrees,DoctorateDegrees,SpecialDegreePrograms) VALUES ('$Name','$BachelorsDegrees', '$Certifications', '$Diplomas', '$AssociateDegrees', '$MastersDegrees', '$DoctorateDegrees','$SpecialDegreePrograms')") or die(mysql_error()) ;
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }

} 
}
else
{
echo mysql_error();
}
```

This is how they look like in the database:

DoctorateDegrees seems to be working fine but it duplicate itself.

If I put

```
<p>Onion1<br>
Onion2<br>
Onion3</p>
```

into the textarea box, they will each have their own row, but it will keep repeating like this:

```
<p>Onion1<br>
Onion2<br>
Onion3</p>
<p>Onion1<br>
Onion2<br>
Onion3</p>
<p>Onion1<br>
Onion2<br>
Onion3</p>
```

Other columns, for example, BachelorsDegrees (which had been working fine before I inserted the additional foreach code), will just repeat the first value:

```
<p>Onion1<br>
<p>Onion1<br>
<p>Onion1<br>
```

MastersDegrees will repeat the same value a certain amount of times:

```
<p>Onion1<br>
<p>Onion1<br>
<p>Onion1<br>
Onion2<br>
Onion2<br>
Onion2<br>
Onion3<br>
Onion3<br>
Onion3<br>
```

Any ideas?

Note: `BachelorsDegrees` *was* working before when I was testing it before adding in the other columns.

Comment: It's difficult to answer this one. Could you provide test input data? Explain what you want vs what you get in the database? The inner loops will repeat their complete range of values for each iteration of an outer loop. Even if there's only 3 values in each loop array and 7 levels of loops you will get each $textAr value 3*3*3*3*3*3 times. So are you **sure** BachelorsDegrees "just repeats the first value"?

Comment: Yes. it only works when BachelorsDegrees is on its own, meaning the other foreach loops and arrays are not in the code.  When I put ther est of the code in, the first value is inserted into the database multiple times.  I see the same value in multiple rows.

Comment: Exactly, my point too. Say you have 2 levels of foreach(). Then the outer will take its 1st value and **reuse** it for **each** value in the inner foreach. When inner foreach has run through all its values it is back to outer and its 2nd value. Then the inner foreach will repeat all values again, now with the 2nd value from the outer loop. ..so my gut feeling is that you might want to redesign your code, it might be wrong for what you want.

Comment: hmm, good point.  thanks for the knowledge :)  but what would be the best way to redesign it?  I need to have multiple values from multiple textarea boxes to be inserted into the right columns on individual separate rows.

Comment: Sorry, but I need more info for that. I don't know your data, database or how you want the data to be distributed. Do you really want to cram **all** the data into a single table, as implied by your query above? If so, could you please provide an example? Edit/update your question with it?

Comment: I have multiple columns, each column represents a variable (eg: BachelrosDegees).

In the html form, each variable has a textarea box.  Obviously that means I will (or somebody will) insert multiple values into the text area.  I don't want multiple values to be in one row in one column.  I want each value to be on separate rows under the column it belongs in.

If the values in the BachelorsDegrees textarea box were: Nursing, IT, Medicine....then there should be 3 rows of values in the BachelorsDegrees column.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend that you split your College_Courses table into several smaller tables. Probably one per column(mentioned above). Unless I'm missing something. A rule of thumb in database design is to not bundle a lot of dissimilar properties in the same table like that.

If you still want to stick to the one table approach you should separate your foreach loops and do INSERT queries in each loop, not nest them like they are now. You'll end up with a huge table with a lot of unused space in it, though.